# Clear <input> field from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

To pass values from javascript to the code behind after a postback I use this code:

```
string strRowNumberTblOne = Request.Form["iRowNumberTblOne"];

<input type="hidden" id="iRowNumberTblOne" name="iRowNumberTblOne" value="" />
```

Is there a way to clear the input field from the code behind?
The Request.Form is read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `runat="server"`. Then set its `Value` property.

Comment: I don't get the value back anymore if I add teh runat statement

Comment: Hidden Values should be updated for Each PostBck..? Use Hidden TextField.?

Answer (score 2):

Try this Instead of you can use Hidden TextBox , like this

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" style="display:none" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**In JavaScript**

```
 varResult = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox2.ClientID%>');
```